# Translating oracle sql listagg function to Bigquery

Tags: sql, oracle, function, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble translating a query from Oracle SQL into BigQuery. Below is what I have so far. Any help is appreciated.

```
,LISTAGG(NODE_NAME
                                    || ':'
                                    ||
                                CASE
                                    WHEN RESPONSE IS NULL THEN
                                        PROMPT_STATUS
                                    ELSE
                                        RESPONSE
                                END, '; ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE) WITHIN GROUP(
                                ORDER BY
                                    DIALOG_SEQ
                            ) OVER(
                                PARTITION BY CALL_KEY
                            ) FLOW_SEQ
```

Here is what I have in BigQuery that is close, but doesn't quite match:

```
,string_agg(NODE_NAME 
                            || ':'
                            || CASE
                                    WHEN RESPONSE IS NULL THEN
                                        PROMPT_STATUS
                                    ELSE
                                        RESPONSE
                                END, '; ' 
                            )  OVER(
                                PARTITION BY CALL_KEY 
                                ORDER BY DIALOG_SEQ                               
                            ) FLOW_SEQ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work

```
,string_agg(NODE_NAME 
                        || ':'
                        || CASE
                                WHEN RESPONSE IS NULL THEN
                                    PROMPT_STATUS
                                ELSE
                                    RESPONSE
                            END, '; ' 
                        )  OVER(
                            PARTITION BY CALL_KEY 
                            ORDER BY DIALOG_SEQ  
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                            AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                        ) FLOW_SEQ
```